# (PHP) SQL Statement returns NULL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to return values of these tables, but some return NULL.

**SQL returns this**

[image]

**PHP Code**

```
$query = $PDO->prepare("SELECT s.user_id, s.order_date, s.total_order_price, s.status_id,
    op.id, op.product_id, op.amount, op.order_id, op.price,
    p.product_name, st.status_name FROM orders s
    LEFT JOIN order_products op ON s.id = op.product_id
    LEFT JOIN products p ON op.product_id = p.product_id
    LEFT JOIN status st ON s.status_id = st.id WHERE user_id = $user_id");

$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetch();
```

Comment: can you share your PHP code?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` means that if there's not a value in the right-side table, then you get NULLs. If you only want results where there are records in both tables, use an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: please update your question, instead of pasting code in comment

Comment: if i use `INNER JOIN` on some or all of them, then i will get this warning: Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\webshop_php\includes\profiel.inc.php on line 22

Comment: That warning must be coming from some code you haven't shown us. But it _probably_ implies that fetch() didn't find a row (and therefore returned false - which of course is a bool - instead) and you didn't verify that before trying to access the row data. I strongly suggest testing the query in MySQL Workbench / phpmyAdmin / your MySQL editor of choice before putting it into the PHP

Comment: Your join criteria looks a bit strange though. For example: `ON s.id = op.product_id`...but `s` is the orders table, not products. So surely it should be `ON s.id = op.order_id`? Obviously I can't see your schema, but just based on the names I would guess that is a big part of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I recommend you use some ORM, but if you don't want, you should fix your code like this (for prevent SQL injections). Use at least prepared statements (https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

```
$q = $PDO->prepare("SELECT s.user_id, s.order_date, s.total_order_price, s.status_id,
op.id, op.product_id, op.amount, op.order_id, op.price,
p.product_name, st.status_name FROM orders s
LEFT JOIN order_products op ON s.id = op.product_id
LEFT JOIN products p ON op.product_id = p.product_id
LEFT JOIN status st ON s.status_id = st.id WHERE user_id = :user_id");
//use bind parameters
$q->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id);
$q->execute();
```

Then you should check how many rows you have, if any. And then get all results with `fetchAll`

```
//check count of results
if ($q->rowCount() > 0){
    $result = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($result);
}
```